# What's the full name of A.M.A.Z.O.?

Tags: dc, tv, dc-animated-universe, justice-league

Professor Ivo's nanotechnology based Android was named A.M.A.Z.O. What's the full form of A.M.A.Z.O.? I tried searching the web but without luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Justice League episode "Tabula Rasa", the League discovered Ivo's blueprints for the android, labeled "A.M.A.Z.O." It was never revealed what these letters stood for in the DCAU version of the character. The name "Amazo" was not an acronym in the comics.

Answer (score 5):

A.M.A.Z.O. refers to [Amazo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazo) from DC Comics. Amazo of DC comics also created by Ivo and even have similar powers but different appearances. It's never mentioned in the animated series what A.M.A.Z.O stands for.

> Even though he is called "A.M.A.Z.O." on Ivo's blueprints, he is
>   usually referred to as "Ivo's android" or just "The Android" (Doctor
>   Fate referred to him as "Amazo" on separate occasions, however).

Answer (score 2):

Anti-Metahuman Adaptive Zootomic Organism.

Source: https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/A.M.A.Z.O.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution and welcome here. We prefer answers that are confirmed by sources here. What is the source of your answer?

Comment: That's the Arrowverse one, right?

Comment: @Taladris Googling showed https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/A.M.A.Z.O. This name is a new addition to the DC universe.

Comment: @AvengeTheFallen Fandom (formerly known as Wikia) wikis don't have a very good reputation as reliable sources, so it would be nice to find a better source, in case this is just fan speculation.

Comment: @AvengeTheFallen: great! Then the answer deserves my +1 :)

Comment: @AvengeTheFallen: I edited the link as the url didn't take into account the last dot. You can use the Link button to avoid this problem.